# How can i remove the null from textarea when request.GetAttribute is null, and how can i modify the visibility of the label from the servlet

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsp, servlets

How can i remove the null from textarea when request.GetAttribute is null, and how can i modify the visibility of the label from the servlet?
On the input textarea it doesn't show the request.getattribute value, and on the output textarea it shows the value but when the request.getattirbute is null, null is printed on the textarea and i want to remove it, how?

```
    <label>Type word/s here:</label></br>
    <textarea name="Input" id="styleid">
    <%
    String msg=(String)request.getAttribute("Input");
    if(msg==null)
    {
        msg="";
    }
    %>
    </textarea> </br>
    <input type="submit" class="styled-button-2" value="Translate" name="query" /> </br>
    <textarea name="Output" id="styleid" text="" disabled>
    <%=
    request.getAttribute("Output")
    %>
    </textarea>
```

And on the visibility of the label
JSP

```
     <label for="Syllabication" class="
     <%=request.getAttribute("Visibility")%>">Syllabication</label>
```

Servlet

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    request.setAttribute("Visbility","hidden");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("eng-chav.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

And the hidden class

```
    <style>
    .hidden{
       visibility:hidden;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: consider using the core jstl `c:if`

Comment: I am not sure can you try this request.getAttribute("Output")!=null. With this condition it will display the text area and value if not null . If null it will display the text area and the value will be empty

Comment: It returns the boolean result and displays it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%
String msg=(String)request.getAttribute("Input");
if(msg==null)
{
    msg="";
}
%>
```

This is not outputting anything, since the value is only stored in `msg` and not printed out anywhere. You should probably add:

```
<%=
    msg
%>
```

In the other textarea, you have:
    <%=
    request.getAttribute("Output")
    %>
which will print out `null` when you have no attributed called "Output". So this may be the origin of the `null` you are seeing.

As for the visibility issue, you'll just have to add another class for the case when you want to make the element visible again. For example:

```
<style>
.hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
}
.visible {
   visibility: visible;
}
</style>
```

Then, you make the element visible in your servlet code by writing:

```
request.setAttribute("Visbility","hidden");
```

Comment: How can i remove that null text in the textarea when "Output" is null?

Comment: Same as you did with the "Input". Use `<% String msg=(String)request.getAttribute("Output"); 
if (msg == null ) 
   msg = '';
%> `
then
`<%= msg %>`

Comment: Got it thanks, and when the request is printed to the textarea it always has a blank line on the 1st line